# Color in BarLegend is not consistent with the plot?

Tags: plotting, color, legending

```
lgnds = BarLegend[{{Red, White, Blue}, {-1, 1}}, 
  Ticks -> {{-1, Style["-1", 13, Black]}, {0, 
     Style["0", 13, Black]}, {1, Style["1", 13, Black]}}, 
  LegendMarkerSize -> 150]

DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Red, White, Blue}, Rescale[#, {-1, 1}]] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotLegends -> Placed[lgnds, Above]]
```

In the cod above the `White` color in the `BarLegend` must be at `0`, why is it shifted?

[image]

Comment: `DensityPlot` seems to be rescaling the legend.  Happens with `ContourPlot`, too.  I don't see why it should do that.  Probably a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the option `ColorFunctionScaling -> True` in `BarLegend` the anomaly disappears:

```
lgnds2 = BarLegend[{{Red, White, Blue}, {-1, 1}}, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> True, 
  Ticks -> {{-1, Style["-1", 13, Black]}, {0, 
     Style["0", 13, Black]}, {1, Style["1", 13, Black]}}, 
  LegendMarkerSize -> 150]
```

[image]

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Red, White, Blue}, Rescale[#, {-1, 1}]] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotLegends -> Placed[lgnds2, Above]]
```

[image]

The same issue arises in `ContourPlot` and it is also fixed using `lgnds2`:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here's a workaround:

```
Legended[
 DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Red, White, Blue}, 
      Rescale[#, {-1, 1}]] &), 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False],
Placed[Append[
  lgnds, {LegendLayout -> "Row", Charting`TickSide -> Left}],
 Above]]
```

[image]

Comment: one more thing please, how can I make the number in the BarLegend on the top as in the original plot?

Comment: @HD2006 Add another option: `Append[lgnds, {LegendLayout -> "Row", Charting`TickSide -> Left}]`